# nearest element MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, element

I want to find the index of the nearest element in `x=0:0.1:pi/2` to a given number `z=0.65`.
I did already this, but I want something better:
`[C,I]=min(abs(x-z))`.
`I` is the index of the nearest element.

Comment: Better in terms of what? Time complexity? Do you run this multiple times? Do you know the range of z?

Comment: If you want to use this to do interpolation, you should consider `interp1(x, fx, z, 'nearest')` instead.

Answer (score 6):

`[C, I] = min(abs(x-z))` is what I would do - I can't think of an improvement on that. `[~, I] = min(abs(x-z))` would allow you to not create an unnecessary variable `C`, if you regard that as an improvement.